# The pH of tap water changes with time

Tags: acid-base, everyday-chemistry, ph

My following questions are related to $\mathrm{pH}$ values in irrigation water in plants.

I got a $\mathrm{pH}$ meter and I am measuring the **tap water** and I get an value about 8.

**My first question:** Why it is that high?

To get the $\mathrm{pH}$ down, I am using a $\mathrm{pH}$ regulator of phosphoric acid.

**My second question:** I now have some tap water with $\mathrm{pH}$ of about 6.5 but when this water sits for about 1-2 days, the $\mathrm{pH}$ increases back to 8. Why is it increasing?

Edit: the water with $\mathrm{pH}$ 6.5  tap water adjusted with small amounts of phosphoric acid. This then increases back to 8 when it sits for some time.

Comment: It's that high because your water supplier is (1) giving you water from a confined carbonate-hosted aquifer and a pH of around 8.3 is expected; and it bounces around because (2) it's sounding more and more like you're getting water from a well, and 6.5 is the pH of rainwater, so I'm guessing it rained near you or your water source recently, but the buffering capacity exceeds acid contributions from ambient carbon dioxide after a few days. More info, please.

Comment: What happens if you don't expose the water to air?

Comment: Pure water maintained in contact with air gets a pH value changing between $5.2$ and $5.8$ due to the $\ce{CO2}$ amount in the air, which changes from place to place. This is the consequence of the reaction : $\ce{CO2 + H2O -> H^+ + HCO3^-}$ The solution is slightly acidic because of these $\ce{H+}$ ions. Pure water in contact with air and with chalk or calcium carbonate rocks gets a pH value between $8.2$ and $8.5$, This is due to the fact that the $\ce{H+}$ions  produced by the previous rection have reacted with $\ce{CaCO3}$ according to $\ce{CaCO3 + H^+ -> Ca^{2+} + 2 HCO3^-}$